# urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, urllib

I have a simple code for fastapi oAuth where i read a url to validate the keys in it. I tested them in test and Beta env. But started throwing error in prod env like below
"urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>"

```
import json

from urllib.request import urlopen

jsonurl = urlopen(url="https://" + self.__AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/.well-known/jwks.json")
  
jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
```

Couldn't find any solution onlin for this. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this issue is occurring only when python versions are not same in Dev, Beta and Production environment. Since Dev, Beta are working fine Production might have a different version.

If versions are same then try this below.(Assuming that OS is Windows)

goto https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and download
Win32  OpenSSL v1.1.1h EXE | MSI 54MB Installer version. (Download the 64bit if you have installed 64bit Python download 32bit if your python is 32bit)

Install and run.